# phpunit and AppendIterator data provider?

Tags: php, phpunit

A [PHPUnit data provider allows the return of an iterator](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers), but when using an [AppendIterator](http://php.net/manual/class.appenditerator.php) only the last iterator appended is used.  Am I setting things up wrong or can AppendIterators not be used as PHPUnit data providers?

Test file:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AppendIteratorTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider getAppendIterator
     */
    public function testAppendIterator($item) {
        echo PHP_EOL."test> $item".PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function getAppendIterator() {
        $iterator = new AppendIterator();
        $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[0], [1]]));
        $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[2], [3]]));
        $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[4], [5]]));

        foreach($iterator as $i) {
            echo 'foreach> '.print_r($i, true);
        }

        return $iterator;
    }
}
```

Test file output:

```
    $ vendor/bin/phpunit --debug AppendIteratorTest.php 
        foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )
    foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
    foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )
    foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )
    foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 4
    )
    foreach> Array
    (
        [0] => 5
    )
    PHPUnit 6.2.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


    Starting test 'AppendIteratorTest::testAppendIterator with data set #0 (4)'.
    R
    test> 4

    Starting test 'AppendIteratorTest::testAppendIterator with data set #1 (5)'.
    R                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)
    test> 5


    Time: 24 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

    There were 2 risky tests:

    1) AppendIteratorTest::testAppendIterator with data set #0 (4)
    This test did not perform any assertions

    2) AppendIteratorTest::testAppendIterator with data set #1 (5)
    This test did not perform any assertions

    OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
    Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Risky: 2.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I setting things up wrong or can AppendIterators not be used as PHPUnit data providers?

Sort of wrong. Data-providers in Phpunit support any *`array`* or *`Traversable`* (*`AppendIterator`* is a *`Traversable`*). So it does work (you can see this as you don't get an error).

However there is a (lesser known) detail with data-providers: Each data-set can have a *name*. The *name* is the key of the provided array -or- in case of a *`Traversable`* the value of `Iterator::key()`. For the `ArrayIterator` that are the array keys.

Here your code with the keys made visible as PHP creates them implicitly:

```
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([0 => [0], 1 => [1]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([0 => [2], 1 => [3]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([0 => [4], 1 => [5]]));
```

In your keys these will always be 0 and 1. As you have duplicate keys, the last ones will "win". This is the result you see.

So much as an explanation what is going on.

One solution then could be:

```
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([0 => [0], 1 => [1]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([2 => [2], 3 => [3]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([4 => [4], 5 => [5]]));
```

There is no default Iterator in PHP which would re-number the keys, also I don't have one in [*Iterator Garden*](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden) (*`IndexingIterator`* comes close, Börgers examples are down, [Nikic iter lib's `reindex`](https://github.com/nikic/iter/blob/702c013/src/iter.php#L138-L168) can do it, ...) a quick inline in your case would be yielding reindexed:

```
public function getAppendIterator() {
    $iterator = new AppendIterator();
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[0], [1]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[2], [3]]));
    $iterator->append(new ArrayIterator([[4], [5]]));

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($iterator as $i) {
        yield $index++ => $i;
    }
}
```

Here the `$index` counter is used as key in the `yield` statement. This makes your data-provider return a *`Generator`* which is a *`Traversable`* again. Phpunit then can handle it.

The problem is similar when you have multiple data-provider methods that do return data-sets with string keys. All string keys must be unique otherwise the provided data will be overwritten again.

That is b/c internally the data-sets from each data-provider is turned into an array explicitly.

I hope this answers your question and also helps you to create the data-provider you're looking for.

Comment: THANKS @hakre!  Now that I read your answer it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between using foreach syntax.

(a) `foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) { echo "$key = $value\n"; }`

(b) `foreach ($iterator as $value) { echo "$value\n"; }`

When using key in the loop the problem will occur, because of duplicated key values. Therefore the last value win. In case (b) when the key is not used, the iteration will be according to the order in which iterators where appended. Notice that all values are displayed in case (b).

There is a method to extract all values from the iterator called `iterator_to_array`. This method can help you solve the problem with duplicated keys. It has an additional argument to not use original keys. It will create a new unique numeric index for each value.

Example `$all_values = iterator_to_array($iterator, false);`

I know that is sort of old topic, but the answer can be helpful for other users.